# Best practices for accessing data between Rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I have two Rails applications whose data are pretty interdependent.  If I needed to easily access models of another application in Django or otherwise share them, this was trivial, as I would simply include both applications in my project and be able to import the models of the other application.  At that point, I could just access objects in the other app's database using Django's ORM and it was consistent and awesome.

In Rails, I'm getting the overwhelming vibe that the way to do this is by creating RESTful API hooks in each application for each thing you want the other application to request.  Seems clean and modular enough, but it's starting to get messy because I have a situation as follows:

1. Make GET request to application A
2. Application A needs to fetch data from application B, so it makes a GET request to an API hook on application B.
3. As part of the function in B's controller, it needs data that is part of A's data model, so it makes requests to A.
4. Steps 2-3 are happening in succession

It's obvious this is creating a scalability nightmare and in our case, requests are timing out because of this race condition in which the new requests are waiting for the original request to complete but it never will until the new ones complete.  We can spin up more web server processes, but I feel like there has got to be a better way to do this that doesn't involve making these superfluous GET requests when I maintain both of these applications.

Ultimately, my questions are 1) is there a more direct approach to getting another Rails app's data than issuing a GET request, or am I just trying to use what's actually a great design in a way that is killing it? and 2) If I am fighting against the grain of the design pattern and this really is a great approach, is there any general advice you can offer that will help me keep the data in these apps from having a dependency on one another that causes race conditions like this?  I realize I could pass the information that app B will need from A up front (it is just one field right now but could later be more), but is that *right*?

Comment: If Application B is going to need data from Application A to complete the request from Application A why not just pass that data along with the request to Application B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a large portion of shared data/models, put those models into a gem/plugin and use them in both apps. Keep the DB config per-app, though, IMO.

If they're that tightly interwoven, I'm not 100% convinced that one or both apps are doing it right, though.

Comment: I think making it a gem is the perfect candidate. The code in question is a module of one application that handles making/tracking short links. It's important enough that it needs to be its own module now. Thanks!

Comment: @Aaron No problem. We just did the same thing a few weeks ago when we wanted to split the admin portion off of the main app.

Answer (score 0):

I also happened to discover that Mongoid has support for multiple databases, which allows us to do *exactly* what I was aiming to do: http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/replication.html